# python show all attributes with super()

Tags: python, class, attributes

```py
@dataclass
class vehicle():
    attributex: int
    attributey: int
    attributez: int
    
@dataclass
class Bus(vehicle):
    attribute1: int
    attribute2: int
    attribute3: int
                   
@dataclass
class Bike(vehicle):
    attribute4: int
    attribute5: int
    attribute6: int
```

now I want a code that shows me all attributes like that:

```
>>> bike1 = Bike(1,2,3,4,5,6)
>>> print(bike1.show_data)
attributex: 1 attributey: 2 attributez: 3 attribute1: 4 attribute2: 5 attribute3: 6
```

thanks for helping.

Comment: Look at `bike1.__dict__`.

Comment: Also read about [dataclasses.asdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict).